# How to test ng-web-apis/geolocation Observable in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, geolocation

I'm trying to test a simple angular 8 service that gets user location using [GeoLocation Service](https://github.com/ng-web-apis/geolocation) from [Web APIs for Angular](https://github.com/ng-web-apis)

```
 public enableGPS() {
    if (!this.locationSubscription)
        this.locationSubscription = this.geoLocationService.subscribe(
            (position) => {
                this._currentLocation = position.coords;
            }
        );
 }
```

And this is the test

```
 describe("Toggle Location Service", () => {

    it("should enable location service", () => {

        const testPosition = {
            position: {
                coords: {
                    longitude: 1.0,
                    latitude: 2.0
                }
            }};

        let geoLocationService: GeolocationService = TestBed.get(GeolocationService);
        spyOn(geoLocationService, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(
            Observable.of(testPosition));
        service.enableGPS();
        expect(service.currentLocation).toEqual(testPosition);
      });
    });
```

but service.currentLocation is always undefined and the subscription callback is never called

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's too late to answer your question, but I just found myself needing to use this in my project.

Well, not to make it any longer and the solution remains because I couldn't make the library work, so use the browser's resources directly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

I created a service that would be the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationService{
    constructor(){
    }
    
    getPosition(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resp => {
                    resolve({lng: resp.coords.longitude, lat: resp.coords.latitude});
                },
                err => {
                    reject(err);
              });
        });
    }
}
```

Then I call it in my component:

```
import { LocationService } from '../Interfaces/Services/location.service';

  location : any = { latitude: '', longitude: '' };
  constructor(
    private _locationService: LocationService
  ) {

  }
  async getLocation() {
    this._locationService.getPosition().then(pos => {
        this.location= {
          latitude: pos.lat,
          longitude: pos.lng
        }
    });
  }
```

I hope it helps you and if not, I hope the answer is clear for future developers